# Use Redis with Wildfly java application server

Tags: redis, wildfly, jedis

I use Wildfly application server and would like to use Redis as datastore service. Redis server is running on the same machine as Wildfly. Do I need some special configuration for Wildfly to access Redis from classes deployed on it?
I use jedis as client for Redis.

Comment: Try and see :) I know nothing about Redis so I can't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that there is nothing special about accessing Redis server form code deployed on application server - everything is the same (at least when both servers are running on localhost):

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
System.out.println("Db size = " + jedis.dbSize());
```

Works fine.